# switch case do while nesting

Tags: c, switch-statement, do-while, nested

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n=0, i=2;
    switch(1)
    {
    case 0:do
           {
    case 1: n++;
    case 2: n++;
           }while(--i > 0);
    }
    printf("n = %d",n);
}
```

I was expecting output for above code to be 0, as case 1 and case 2 are inside a do while which is inside case 0. Switch is testing on value 1, so case 0 will never be executed and hence neither case 1 or 2.

value of n coming to be 4. Any explanation ?

Comment: Each case needs to be an atomic code block - you cannot nest cases within other cases.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll: what's that supposed to mean? Switch cases aren't required to be blocks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/514118/how-does-duffs-device-work

Comment: This is perfectly value C, if obfuscated and P45-inducing on the grounds of unmaintainability. Interesting question though, +1.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll That is incorrect. If a case statement has no break then execution will fall through.

Comment: I think a `break` within the `do` loop will exit the loop rather than the `switch`.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Yes, a `break` refers to the nearest enclosing `switch`, `while`, `do`, or `for` statement. Whereas a `continue` refers to the nearest enclosing `while`, `do`, or `for` statement. (Could be IOCCC fodder.)

Comment: @Code-Apprentice falling through is not the same as nesting.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll The OP is about nesting a do while loop in a switch not about nesting cases within other cases.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mixed 'switch' and 'while' in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25592451/mixed-switch-and-while-in-c)

Answer (score 7):

Your code jumps into the middle of a loop. From that point on, it ignores the cases of the switch statement, so it does `n++`, `n++`, check condition, loop, etc. It helps if you think of a `case` as a label, and `switch` as a `goto`:

```
    int n=0, i=2;

    if (1 == 0)
        goto label0;
    else if (1 == 1)
        goto label1;
    else if (1 == 2)
        goto label2;

label0:
    do {
        puts("loop");
label1:
        n++;
label2:
        n++;
    } while (--i > 0);
```

Like your original code, this simply skips the part of the loop body before `label1` (the `puts`), then continues as if it had entered the loop in the normal way.

Comment: @larsmans : With your explanation that case are label - wouldn't it cause problem for nested switch, if both outer and inner switch has same case statements. E.g.
if I put following in case 0
switch (i)
{
case 1: printf("here1");
case 2: printf("here2");
}

now label1 and label2 should conflict as they have a function scope. Please elaborate more on this. 

FYI - I don't get any error though for doing above.

Comment: @Sagrian: A `case ...:` label is associated with the nearest enclosing `switch` statement. There's no ambiguity.