# switch case isn't true than also its executing case which is inside the failed one

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
 int main()
{
     switch(2)
    {
            case 1:
                    if(1)
                    {
                            case 2:
                                    printf("hello\n");
                    };
    }
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT = hello
as I'm passing `2` in `switch` 
`case 1` is not true then also it enters it and executes code inside `case 2`.
How come it enters `case 1`? 
Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, `switch(2)` does not make a lot of sense either. You usually switch on the value of a variable. AFAICT, it does not enter `case 1:`, it jumps to `case 2:` directly. And `if(1)` is useless too.

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569416/how-can-duffs-device-code-be-compiled

Answer (score 2):

After `switch(2)`, it will jump immediately to the `case 2` label. The fact that it is within an `if` block contained within `case 1` is irrelevant. `case 2:` effectively functions no differently from a `goto` label, so it will jump to it wherever it is. It is not true that case 1 is somehow being entered.

To clarify, properly indented it looks thus:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
  switch(2) {
  case 1:
    if(1) {
  case 2:
      printf("hello\n");
    }
    ;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> how come it enters case 1 ?

It doesn't enter the `case 1`. In fact `if(1)` has no use here. The above code is equivalent to

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    switch(2)
    {
        case 1:
        case 2: printf("hello\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

To see the irrelevant use  of `if` you can replace `if(1)` with `if(0)` and you will  find that result will be the same.

Comment: through its o/p i also know that its similar 2 what u say but , my question is how ?