# Why is case statement allowed inside block for another case?

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I've ran across code that looks like this:

```
  switch(i) {
    case 2: {
      std::cout << "2";
      break;
    case 3:
      std::cout << "3";
      break;
    }
    case 4: {
      std::cout << "4";
      break;
    }    
  }
```

Notice that `case 2` opens a block with curly brace, which is closed only after `case 3`. At first this seemed like a typo that would either cause a compiler error, or, even worse, ignore `case 3`. But it works just fine in c++ and outputs 3 if i is 3. I come from java background so my understanding of logical blocks in c++ may be lacking. So my question is: is this deliberate behavior?

Comment: The inner braces are modestly pointless but do no harm.  There are worse things you can do with case labels than that.

Comment: `switch` statements in C and C++ are not as _logic_ as you may think. See the [Duff's device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device) for an extreme example.

Comment: The cases are scoped by the switch - nothing else. One of many reasons not to use them.

Comment: It could have scoped a variable, but no variables in sight here.

Comment: @NeilButterworth, not to use **what** exactly?

Comment: @Serg  switches, in general

Comment: @NeilButterworth, that is a far-reaching statement, with which I can not agree.

Comment: @Serg Fair enough, but it is my firmly held opinion. The overuse of switch-based programming is a blight, and those that think that switches will magically speed up their code are deluded. But from your answer here I guess you are happy with goto-style programming?

Comment: @NeilButterworth, switches, when used reasonably, provide good readability (as compared with long list of `if...else if...` statements) and, in some cases, provided optimization benefits. The former benefit outweights  the latter.

Comment: @Serg We disagree - lets leave it at that.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Actually, there's no "magic" to the belief that `switch` blocks make faster code on average, just simple logic.  A `switch` block does one check and one or two jumps (jump to `case`, jump out at `break` (if present)), while an unoptimised `if..else if..else` chain does one check & jump (either to `else`, or to the end of the chain) per `if` executed (meaning that for an `if..else if..else if..else` block, it does 1-3 checks & jumps).  For any block that can be written as either, the `switch` would thus be slightly more efficient on average.

Comment: [For any block that can be written as either, though, a smart compiler could just optimise it to a jump table anyways if you let it, so it'd still be a `switch` block after compilation.  Haven't tested whether any actually _do_ this, however.]

Comment: A switch block is a strong hint to an optimizing compiler that it should optimize it to a jump table. A series of if statements is a strong hint that it should not. I have seen cases where a compiler will transform a series of if statements into a jump table, @Justin, but the vast majority of the time, it will not. The assumption is that you will write what you mean. If there are more cases than would be readable for a series of if statements, then you'd write it as a switch-case, and it should be compiled as a jump table. Otherwise, the overhead of a jump table is a performance loss.

Comment: @CodyGray Oh, that's interesting to know.  I thought a jump table would be one of the most efficient ways to handle that kind of situation, since it should logically take fewer instructions.  Didn't know it could have more overhead than a series of `if`s.

Comment: [How can Duff's device code be compiled?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5569416/995714), [How does Duff's device work?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/514118/995714)

Comment: @CodyGray: Compilers should not use otherwise-equivalent language constructs as hints for making optimization decisions. If they do, the inevitable outcome is that programmers write not the form that makes the most sense for their program's logic, but the one that the compiler generates faster code for. An ideal optimizing compiler reduces all flow control to ifs and gotos before doing any optimization.

Comment: Well, I won't argue about the theory or what an "ideal" optimizer will do. I was just speaking about what happens *in practice*. In this case, though, I don't think it's particularly crazy for the reasons I already explained, even if that is the inevitable outcome. A jump table won't take fewer instructions than it would take to implement a simple if/else, and you also have locality to think about. Too much to expand upon in a comment.

Comment: @CodyGray: A jump table is at best 1 instruction (if the input range is already tightly bounded by range analysis) and only a couple more if an initial range check is needed. I'm assuming you also want to count the table size, but if the possible cases are dense in the range the table size is likely smaller than the if/else tree.

Answer (score 9):

You can, but shouldn't, abuse case labels in a `switch` far worse than that — and far worse than [Duff's Device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device).  Duff's Device has the dubious privilege of being almost plausibly useful and yet can be regarded as abusing `switch`.

Not all abuses of `switch` can claim to be plausibly useful.  For instance, this compiles as C or C++, even with stringent warnings set:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    unsigned seed;
    if (argc == 2)
        seed = atoi(argv[1]);
    else
        seed = time(0);
    printf("seed: %u\n", seed);
    srand(seed);

    int i = rand() % 10;
    int j = 21;
    int k = 37;
    printf("i: %d\n", i);
    switch (i)
    {
    case 1:
        for (j = 10; j > i; j--)
        {
        case 2:
            printf("case 2:\n");
            for (k = j - 1; k > 0; k--)
            {
            case 6:
                printf("case 6:\n");
            default:
                printf("%d-%d-%d\n", i, j, k);
            }
        case 5:
            printf("case 5:\n");
            printf("%d-%d\n", i, j);
            break;
        }
        break;
    case 3:
        printf("case 3:\n");
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The argument handling allows you set the seed, so you can reproduce results if you want to.  I'd make no claim that it is useful; indeed, it is not useful.  Note that `break` inside the loops breaks the loop, not the `switch`.

Basically, `case` labels (and `default`) must be within the scope of a `switch`, and are associated with the innermost enclosing `switch`.  There are few other constraints on them.  You have to be careful not to jump over variable initializations, etc (that's why `j` and `k` are defined outside the `switch()`).  But otherwise, they're just labels, and control will flow to them when 'appropriate'.

Answer (score 6):

`switch` statement in C/C++ is a glorified `goto` statement (with some optimization benefits).

As a result, you can do as much with `case` labels as you'd do with `goto` labels. In particular, jumping inside the block is allowed, as long as you are not bypassing any variable initialization.