# Nested case statements

Tags: c, switch-statement, duffs-device

Can some one please explain the nesting of `case` statements into another. I'm referring to the  [Duffs Device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device) where all other `case` statements are inside the `do-while` loop associated with `case 0`. I cant get my head around it. It seems to me that it should act like a nested `if`. But then i'm definitely missing something. Please explain.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does Duff's device work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/514118/how-does-duffs-device-work)

Comment: Don't be ashamed of not being able to wrap your head around Duff's device...

Comment: my question is about the nested `case` statements, I used Duffs device as a reference because i ended up there while doing research about the this behavior in the first place. I have already seen the link above and does not quite help. Sorry.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Case statements aren't blocks, they don't nest. Duff's device does not involve nesting switch statements. Post an example of code you don't understand.

Comment: Like i said i was missing something. I read through K&R appendix A section A9 (2nd ed. pg. 222). World makes much more sense now.

Answer (score 3):

In a `switch-case` construct, the `switch` body is just a normal or compound statement which can contain any other valid c statements. It  may also contain `case` or `default` labels.
And the control jumps to appropriate case label depending on controlling expression value, the statements in the switch body are executed one after another just like any other scope `{` `}` unless a `break` is encountered.

For example, consider the following **[simple test program](http://ideone.com/e24yJ)**:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i = 6;//5,10;
    switch(6)
    {
        case 10:
              printf("\nIn case 10");
        case 11:
              printf("\nIn case 11");              
        case 12:
              printf("\nIn case 12");
              break;
        case 5:
              printf("\nIn case 5");
              break;
        case 6:
              printf("\nIn case 6");     
        default:
              printf("\nIn Default");

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Consider 3 values for the controlling expression `i` in the `switch` statement:

```
5   
6
10
```

The resultant outputs are as follows:
**Scenario 1:** `i = 6`

```
In case 6
In Default
```

**Scenario 2:** `i = 10`

```
In case 10
In case 11
In case 12
```

**Scenario 3:** `i = 5`

```
In case 5
```

Notice that, in each of the above scenarios, once a matching `case` label is encountered the statements are executed sequentially until a `break` is encountered, Thereby leading to conclusion which is the first statement in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to understand Duff's device is to separate its two logical components, the `switch` and the `do/while` loop, from each other. Here is a logically equivalent implementation, where the two statements are no longer nested:

```
void copy(int* to, int* from, int count) {
    int n = (count + 7) / 8;
    switch(count % 8) {
        case 0: goto case_0;
        case 1: goto case_1;
        case 2: goto case_2;
        case 3: goto case_3;
        case 4: goto case_4;
        case 5: goto case_5;
        case 6: goto case_6;
        case 7: goto case_7;
    }
    do {
        case_0: *to++ = *from++;
        case_7: *to++ = *from++;
        case_6: *to++ = *from++;
        case_5: *to++ = *from++;
        case_4: *to++ = *from++;
        case_3: *to++ = *from++;
        case_2: *to++ = *from++;
        case_1: *to++ = *from++;
    } while (--n);
}
```

Note the labels inside the loop: they are normal C labels, not `case` labels.

The only difference between this code and Duff's device is that Duff's code exploits the ability of using `case` labels inside a `do/while` loop, as long as the loop itself starts and ends inside the `switch` statement, eliminating the need for "regular" labels and gotos.