# Why it is valid to intertwine switch/for/if statements in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer

I'm reading `boost/asio/coroutine.hpp` and cannot understand the implementation of BOOST_ASIO_CORO_REENTER and BOOST_ASIO_CORO_YIELD. The expanded form of

```
reenter (this) {
  yield ..
  yield ..
}
```

seems to be intertwined switch/if/for statements. I'm wondering how come this is valid C code?  I wrote something similar (shown below) and found it compiles using gcc.

```
int main() {
  int a = 1;
  switch (a)
  case 0: if (1) a = 2;
  else case 1: for (;;) {
    case 3:
      break;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is some [Duff's device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device) trickery.

Comment: If you are using boost, then you are writing C++, not C. So you should be asking why this is valid C++, not why it is valid C (even if the answers would probably be quite similar).

Comment: Care to include some of the original code ?

Comment: [switch statement with do-while interleaved](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9595242/995714), [How does Duff's device work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/514118/995714)

Comment: This has exacfly nothing to do with [tag:boost-asio]. It is a syntax question. Don't tag indiscriminately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntactically, the body of a switch is just a statement (usually, but not necessarily a compound statement)

[6.8](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8):

```
statement:
               labeled-statement
               compound-statement
               expression-statement
               selection-statement
               iteration-statement
               jump-statement
```

which may be labeled
[6.8.1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.1):

```
labeled-statement:
                identifier : statement
                case constant-expression : statement
                default : statement
```

Example:

```
switch(1) one: case 1: dothis();
```

If it is a compound statement, then each substatement recursively may also be labeled. Example:

```
switch(x) {
    if(1) one: case 1: dothis();
    else case 0: orthis();  /*fallthru*/
    three: case 3: three();
}
```

The syntax treats `case`/`default`-labels and regular labels the same, only the semantic check verifies that `case`/`default`-labels be inside a `switch`.

Implementation-wise, everything compiles into (flat) assembly.

E.g.

```
if(test) YesBranch; else ElseBranch;
```

is flattened into (pseudo-assembly)

```
IF_NOT_THEN_GOTO(test, PAST_YES_BRANCH)
YesBranch
goto PAST_NO_BRANCH;
NoBranch
PAST_NO_BRANCH:;
```

and there's no reason why anything in such flat code couldn't be labeled.

`case`/`default` labels are also just like regular labels except they're also used in (most usually) a computed jump.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is because [switch statements](https://wiki.c2.com/?SwitchStatement) aren't structured control flow statements. Instead, they should be considered as syntactic sugar for static dispatch. Dispatch means that the control flow is redirected and static means that the compiler knows where it is redirected to.

So your code

```
int a = 1;
switch (a)
case 0: if (1) a = 2;
else case 1: for (;;) {
  case 3:
    break;
}
return 0;
```

would be compiled into something roughly equivalent of

```
int a = 1;
void *dest = dispatch(a, { case0_addr, case1_addr, case3_addr });
goto *dest;
case0_addr:
if (1) { 
  a = 2;
} else {
case1_addr:
  for (;;) {
    case3_addr:
    goto case_end;
  }
}
case_end:
return 0;
```

where `dispatch` is a function the compiler runs for emitting the machine code required for the static dispatch. Since all dispatch values are constants and all dispatch targets are known by the compiler, it can generate very efficient machine code.

As for why it is legal, I guess the reason is because there's no particular reason for it to be illegal. As shown, `case` statements are just goto labels so they can be placed wherever.