# Cannot figure the output

Tags: c++, for-loop, do-while

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Duff’s device work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514118/how-does-duffs-device-work)

```
int n=5;
int q=(n+3)/4;
switch(n%4)
{ 
  case 0:do{ n++;
  case 3:n++;
  case 2:n++;
  case 1:n++;}while(--q>0);
}
 cout<<n;
```

What will the value of n be? 
This is just the code snippet and the answer that is given is 10. Cannot see how?

Comment: make it compile and use a debugger to step through it and observe the variables changing

Comment: Case labels are just labels, and `switch` is just a `goto`. Maybe that helps.

Comment: Go step by step. How much are `n` and `q` before entering the switch? To what case the execution goes? What happens after that?

Comment: I don't think it will compile with a loop inside of a switch

Comment: I think `n` should be 12 in the end, not 10.

Comment: @aleguna probably shouldn't ! ;)

Comment: Well I have learned something here, Duff's Device. After all my c programming years I never managed to write anything as convoluted and unreadable as this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final value of `n` is 10. Before the switch `n` is 5, and `q` is 2. Switch goes to case 1. `n` is incremented 1 time in first iteration, and 4 more times in second. Finally `n` has the value 5+1+4 = 10.

Comment: Well, yes, now that the code is edited, `n` is indeed 10.