# Control structures inside switch statements

Tags: c++, switch-statement

why the code inside the if block executed any way?

```
switch(v)
{
case a:
    break;
...
if(condition)
{
    case f:
        ...
        break;
    case g:
        ...
        break;
}
...
case z:
    ...
    break;
default:
}
```

Comment: Because the conditional branch is never executed. Control flow never reaches your `if(condition)` line.

Comment: Perhaps because `switch` can jump to any `case` inside, but more code is necessary.

Comment: It's quite a long time since I saw such a weird and unintuitive code like this last time.

Comment: Is this code you found somewhere, or something that you want to accomplish?

Comment: @MrLister I wanted the cases inside the "if block", considered if the condition were true, they are options of a menu, i wanted that those options just considered when a certain situation is true.

Comment: OK, go with Veger's solution then.

Comment: An example of a similar construct that has actually been used: [How does Duff's device work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/514118/how-does-duffs-device-work)

Answer (score 9):

The C++ compiler uses a lookup table or direct branches to the `case`-statements. Ignoring your the `if`-statement. Due to the `break` it is also not reached from `case a`.

Long answer short you cannot 'turn off' `case`-statements using this method.

Instead you'd need something like this:

```
switch(v) {
  case a :
    break;
  //...
  case f :
    if(condition) {
      //...
    }
    break;
  case g :
    if(condition) {
      //...
    }
    break
  //...
  case z :
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A `case` *label*, as the name implies, is an actual label and works very similar to a `goto` label: the execution thread just jumps to it. It does not matter what structure it is in, unless that structure is another, nested `switch` statement.

It works the same way as this:

```
if (v == f)
    goto f_label;

if (condition) {
    f_label:
    // ...
}
```

The execution thread will jump to the `f_label:` label regardless of whether `condition` is true or not. `switch` labels work the same way.

Comment: i want to select ur answer as my accepted one but, it should be if(v != a) goto f;

Comment: @csstd Actually it's `if (v == f)`. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The case clauses for a switch are quite flexible and you can do some `hacks` for them. I have seen some people use switch to break out of nested for loops for instance. Still in the example above if v is `f` or `g` the switch will just skip the if statement and the code in the case will be executed right after switch.

Answer (score 1):

When program is compiling `switch` builds some table to jump from one `case` to another. This jumps somehow ignoring other conditional operations. BTW according to such behavior `switch` is faster than long `if-else` blocks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best answer to how is( inspired from the answer of Nikos C.):

```
switch(v)
{
case a:
    break;

case z:
    ...
    break;
default:
    if(condition)
    {
        switch(v)
        {
        case f:
            ...
            break;
        case g:
            ...
            break;

        default:
            //former default
        }

    }
    else
        //former default
}
```

Comment: +1, best solution since the condition only appears once and it is correct (in contrast to if/else around two separate switches).

Answer (score 0):

Switch jumps to the matched case ignoring all statements in between. You have two ways to accomplish what you intend to do (depending upon the number of cases you have to implement):

Method 1 for more number of cases under the if conditional

```
  if(condition) {
  switch(v) {
  case f :
    ....
    break;
  //...
  case g :
    ....
    break;
  //...
  case z :
    break;
}


  switch(v) {
  case a :
    ....
    break;
  //...
}
```

Method 2 for less cases under the if conditional

```
    switch(v) {
  case a :
    break;
  //...
  case f :
    if(condition) {
      //...
    }
    break;
  case g :
    if(condition) {
      //...
    }
    break
  //...
  case z :
    break;
}
```

Comment: The first method isn't correct. If the condition is true, `case a` should also be considered, but in your code, it isn't.