# Do..while inside switch

Tags: c, loops, optimization, switch-statement

I found some C code that has this structure:

```
switch (n) {
  do {
     case 1:
       // do some things
       if (some condition)
          goto go_on;
     case 2:
       // do some things
       if (some condition)
          goto go_on;
     case 3:
       // do some things
       if (some condition)
          goto go_on;
  } while (1);
  do {
     case 4:
       // do some things
       if (some condition)
          goto go_on;
     case 5:
       // do some things
       if (some condition)
          goto go_on;
  } while (1);
}

go_on:
```

I programmed in C for years (many years ago) and would have thought this would be a syntax error. I think it has something to do with optimizing the loop, but I was wondering if someone could explain what it does. What happens when a `while(1)` is reached, does it effectively go back to the switch? And in particular why are there two do..while's in there?

By the way, I *don't* want to start a discussion on the use of `goto` or if this is bad design. I didn't write this and I assume the author did it this way because it made the loop run as fast as possible.

Comment: Looks like a variation of [Duff's Device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff's_device). There's an [explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514118/how-does-duffs-device-work).

Comment: Think of the `case` statements as labels with the `switch` as a `goto`.

Comment: this is some kind of loop unrolling technique. think about the loop end.

Comment: It shows how far people are willing to mangle their code and twist it into pretzels just to avoid one or two `goto`s.

Comment: @Mike Dunlavey - yeah, I guess so. Or maybe the author was happy with the code generated by the switch statement. The original code has cases for 0 to 9, so maybe a jump table is faster than a bunch of ifs. BTW, maybe I should have mentioned in the question (just for those interested) that the original code is here: [link](http://wwwhomes.uni-bielefeld.de/achim/prime_sieve.html), so you can see it's kind of old.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey They're not avoiding `goto`s, there's still 5 of them!  It's more about application programmers believing they know more about optimization than compiler programmers, and their willingness to sacrifice readability to demonstrate it.

Comment: @bcrist: FYI I have measured significant performance increases in some code by using Duff's Device in VC9.

Comment: @MooingDuck Ignoring any arguments over premature optimization and whether or not a 6 year old compiler should be used for performance-critical applications, this is not Duff's Device, even if it looks similar.  Duff's Device tests the exit condition in the `while`, not in each `case`.

Comment: It *should* be a syntax error.  Gag!!!

Answer (score 6):

Equivalent code that may better show program flow.

Akin to [Duff's device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff's_device) to allow entering a loop at some intermediate position. @ tangrs

General frowned upon these days as 1) compilers typically do a better job at optimizing & 2) as OP has found, can easily obscure the meaning of the code.  Use with caution.

In OP's code, after either `while` condition, program flow does not return back to the `switch` statement. The `switch` and `case` only affect the initial entry into the `while` loops.

```
if (n == '1') goto case1;
if (n == '2') goto case2;
...
if (n == '5') goto case5;
goto go_on;

do {
  case1:
     // do some things
     if (some condition) goto go_on;
  case2:
     // do some things
     if (some condition) goto go_on;
  case3:
     // do some things
     if (some condition) goto go_on;
} while (1);

do {
  case4:
    // do some things
    if (some condition) goto go_on;
  case5:
    // do some things
    if (some condition) goto go_on;
} while (1);

go_on:
```

---

[Edit]

There are 2 `while` loops to accommodate the original coder's flow to jump into intermediate points into 1 of 2 loops.

Candidate re-write follows.  Having access to the overall code, certainly a cleaner solution can be  had.

```
int n2 = n;  // Only evaluate n once as in the switch statement.
if (n2 >= 1) {
  if (n2 <= 3) {
    while (1) {
      if (n2 <= 1) {
        // do some things
        if (some condition) { break; }
      }
      if (n2 <= 2) {
        // do some things
        if (some condition) { break; }
      }
      // do some things
      if (some condition) { break; }
      n2 = 1;
    }

  else if (n2 <= 5) {
    while (1) {
      if (n2 <= 4) {
        // do some things
        if (some condition) { break; }
      }
      // do some things
      if (some condition) { break; }
      n2 = 4;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, to you and the others who answered. It makes perfect sense now. In fact I'm a little chagrined that I couldn't figure that out myself. Maybe I'm getting too old for this stuff!

Comment: @kh99, doubt if too old.  This technique works slick and may meet the need in very select situations.  But IMO, maintenance is more expensive that original coding and coding should avoid difficult to maintain undocumented snippets like this.  Not so great a loss to not have come by it earlier.

Comment: I'm not sure about the "certainly cleaner" part of the second block.  But I am sure of its inequivalence.  In the first block `n` is only used to determine the starting place in the loop and is not rechecked again once inside the loop.

Comment: @John  1) I was not trying to imply the candidate solution here was cleaner.  I meant a cleaner solution to the candidate was possible if the overall code and its goals where known.  2) The first loop is functionally equivalent as at the bottom of the loop `n2` is set to '1', rendering subsequent iteration's `if (n2 <= 1 or 2) always true.

Answer (score 6):

Let me rewrite this code for you, maybe this will make it more obvious. The following code is more or less equivalent to the one you posted:

```
if (n == 1) goto ONE;
if (n == 2) goto TWO;
if (n == 3) goto THREE;
if (n == 4) goto FOUR;
if (n == 5) goto FIVE;
goto SKIP_ALL;

while (true) {
ONE:
    // do some things
    if (some condition) goto go_on;
TWO:
    // do some things
    if (some condition) goto go_on;
THREE:
    // do some things
    if (some condition) goto go_on;
}

while (true) {
FOUR:
    // do some things
    if (some condition) goto go_on;
FIVE:
    // do some things
    if (some condition) goto go_on;
}

SKIP_ALL:
go_on:
```

The loops are within the switch, they don't cause the switch to take place more often. The switch basically decides to which loop the program flow jumps and at which instruction within that loop it starts. Once it jumped there, the loops continue normally. Also note that a switch is usually faster than all those `if` statements.

And no, goto is not bad design in general. A `switch` is merely just a goto and a switch is not bad design. In reality, pretty much every code branch within a function/method executed on a CPU or within a VM is a simple goto (sometimes a conditional one, sometimes not). It's just that goto is most primitive, low level way of branching and tells the reader little about the intention. Whenever there is a higher level one, one that makes your intention more obvious, it is preferable to use that one instead. Using a goto is only bad design if you could have easily written the same kind of code without using a goto and it would not have been much worse either. In some (albeit very rare) cases a goto is almost unavoidable or any attempt to avoid it creates ugly, unreadable, very complex code or very poor performance as a result.

The "goto considered harmful" essay comes from a time, where some people were using goto for everything: For if/else code branches, for loops, for switches, to break out of loops/switches, to avoid recursion, etc. And if you overuse goto like that and if you do things like jumping to a label that immediately jumps to another label, people lose overview. Code like this is unreadable and extremely hard to debug. This is the way how you write assembly code, but that shouldn't be the way how we write C code.

Answer (score 1):

All cases are simply labels. So if to remove the switch statement the code will look like

```
  do {
     case '1':
       // do some things
       if (some condition)
          goto go_on;
     case '2':
       // do some things
       if (some condition)
          goto go_on;
     case '3':
       // do some things
       if (some condition)
          goto go_on;
  } while (1);
  do {
     case '4':
       // do some things
       if (some condition)
          goto go_on;
     case '5':
       // do some things
       if (some condition)
          goto go_on;
  } while (1);

go_on:
```

So there are two ordinary infinite do-while loops that stop iterations depending on some internal conditions in the loops. You could write this code even simpler

```
  do {
       // do some things
       if (some condition)
          goto go_on;
       // do some things
       if (some condition)
          goto go_on;
       // do some things
       if (some condition)
          goto go_on;
  } while (1);

  do {
       // do some things
       if (some condition)
          goto go_on;
       // do some things
       if (some condition)
          goto go_on;
  } while (1);

go_on:
```

So what does add the switch to the code shown above? It only provides entry points to the loops bypassing the normal entry points of the loops. That is the first iterations will start from some case label and nothing more. Also if there is no appropriate case label then the loops will be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if my variant is any better, but I'd write

```
switch (n) {
    LOOP1:
        // do some things
        if (some condition)
            break;
    case 2:
        // do some things
        if (some condition)
            break;
    case 3:
        // do some things
        if (some condition)
            break;
        goto LOOP1;
    case 4:
    LOOP4:
        // do some things
        if (some condition)
            break;
    case 5:
        // do some things
        if (some condition)
            break;
        goto LOOP4;
}
```

The original is pretty confusing because of the `switch-do-while`. All replacement solutions use some `goto`s, and actually many of them, and/or nested complicated conditions. So I instead replaced the confusing `do-while` by a `goto`.

---

You could simplify

```
        if (some condition)
            break;
        goto LOOP4;
```

into

```
        if (!some condition) goto LOOP4;
```

but I prefer to keep it uniform.

---

If you can extract

```
    // do some things
    if (some condition)
        break;
```

into a function, the you can write

```
switch (n) {
    case 1: while (true) {
        if (body1()) break;
        if (body2()) break;
        if (body3()) break;
    }
    break;
    case 2: while (true) {
        if (body2()) break;
        if (body3()) break;
        if (body1()) break;
    }
    break;
    case 3: while (true) {
        if (body3()) break;
        if (body1()) break;
        if (body2()) break;
    }
    break;
    case 4: while (true) {
        if (body4()) break;
        if (body5()) break;
    }
    break;
    case 5: while (true) {
        if (body5()) break;
        if (body4()) break;
    }
}
```

It's bit repetitive, but pretty clear and uses no fall-though.

Comment: @chux Thanks, fixed. But now, it's even more repetitive.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this sort of structure before.  It's possible that the author was writing a state machine of some sort.  (See the source to zlib for an example.)

Does the "do some stuff" part change n to whatever case will run next?

Comment: The original code I was looking at is here: [link](http://wwwhomes.uni-bielefeld.de/achim/prime_sieve.html) . As you can see it's a Sieve of Eratosthenes implementation.  I don't believe the n is changed in the loop.