# switch statement in C / Objective C

Tags: objective-c, c, switch-statement

I am new to Objective-C, But from all I know about switch statements, the following code should not print anything, because to me it seems that there should be a compilation error. However 2 is printed. I do not understand why. Could someone please explain?

```
- (void) test {
    int myVar = 2;

    switch (myVar) {
        case 1:
        {
            NSLog(@"result: %d", myVar);
            break;

            case 2:
            {
                NSLog(@"result: %d", myVar);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: a `case:` is not a block or a stand-alone statement. It's a **label.** Think of it as the target of a conditional `goto`.

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes.  This is a very subtle detail of C that is interesting. Does this compile becuase it is valid code or by coincidence of the syntax?  Also,  go look up "Duff's device".

Comment: @bbum it's valid, exactly because `case`s are labels. Also, Duff's device.

Comment: So `case 2:` is reachable because it is visible to the `switch` statement regardless of the scope brackets of `case 1:`?

Comment: I get that it is valid as pure scope & label. To rephrase; this appears to be one of the edge cases where the syntax allows a construct that really should be marked with a warning, at least, for the sake of programmer sanity, but can't. Duff's, at least, follows sane scoping patterns.

Comment: Those aren't "scope brackets". They don't define the scope in this case. They're simply decoration. In fact, you should be able to just add a bunch of `{}` in any case, and it will compile. `gcc -Wall` doesn't even complain.

Comment: Brackets must be used if a variable has to be declared in the body of `case:`. That is how I encountered this issue. My example is stripped to the core.

Comment: It's worth noting that this is not an Objective-C behavior. This behaves as shown in C as well. https://gist.github.com/wjlafrance/ce7581374a47ed65bf44

Comment: @nanny, this decoration can control scope of variables. But it's dangerous of course, because you can define variable in case 1, and use it uninitialized in case 2.

Comment: _My example is stripped to the core_, .... As it should be.  It presents the core of what is needed to convey the question well.

Comment: Note this is not specific to Objective-C.  This is pure C stuff.

Comment: With the later/latest versions of C, a variable can be declared almost anywhere, so the braces '{}' and no longer needed,  So a variable declared inside a switch() statement can be declared anywhere

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can think of the `switch(value){case label:, ...}` construct as a *variable* `goto <label>` statement, where:

***1)***  `switch(arg)` determines which `label` execution will flow to next.
***2)***  The key word ***case :*** defines the ***label***.   Example:  `case label:`.

In a switch statement, the `case` key word is followed by a label (constant expression followed by a `:`), which is treated like the label used in `goto` statements. Control passes to the statement whose `case constant-expression` matches the value of *arg* in the statement `switch(arg)`.

So legally there is nothing *syntactically* wrong with your code. That is, it will compile and build, and run just fine.  The only thing the syntax in your example code violates is *readability* in that the execution flow ignores the block `{...}`, which in most cases would direct execution flow, and jumps directly to the targeted label defined by the `case` key word, just as it should.

It's not often that ignoring well established precedent to experiment with new hybrid constructs will yield useful results.  But when it does, the results can become legendary.  For example, ***[see Duff's Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514118/how-does-duffs-device-work)***.