# questions in c++ (polymerphism, range-based for loop)

Tags: c++

Please understand that I've only begun learning C++. I must be missing some basic understanding because I can't configure:

1. why does the following code changes its output when I replace virtual void f() in class A with void f()? (it prints B when void, C when virtual void)

   ```
   class A{
   public:
       virtual void f(){ 
       cout<<"A";}
       };

   class B:public A{
   public:
       void f(){
       cout<<"B";}
       };
   class C:public B{
   public:
       void f(){cout<<"C";}
       };
   int main(){
       B *p = new C;
       p->f();
       }
   ```
2. Why does the following code print more than "CPP!"?

   ```
   int main (){
        int x[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
   for(int y:x){
   switch(y){
       case 1:cout<<"C";
       case 3:cout<<"P";
       case 7:cout<<"P";
       case 8:cout<<"!";
   }
   ```

   }

I look forward to hearing back from you experts..

Comment: One question per question please.

Comment: What does it print out

Comment: Both questions are very basic. Have you tried to look it up?

Comment: Furthermore you could learn the answers to both questions by reading [a good beginners book or two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Hint for the second question: It's not the `for` loop that's the problem, it's the `switch` (or rather each `case`).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391679/why-do-we-need-virtual-functions-in-c and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33222437/switch-case-statement-without-break

Comment: 1) [virtual keyword for functions in derived classes. Is it necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895294/c-virtual-keyword-for-functions-in-derived-classes-is-it-necessary)

Comment: Thanks for all the inputs.

Comment: `break` please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why does the following code changes its output when I replace virtual void f() in class A with void f()? (it prints B when void, C when virtual void)

When a class inherits from another (like in your case `B` and `C` from `A` and `B` respectively), the `virtual` keyword means that the method it is applied to (`f()`) in your case) can be re-defined for child classes. In your case, it allows classes `B` and `C` to have their own personal implementations for `f()`, through polymorphism. Notice how in your `main()` you create a `C` object, and not a `B`:

```
B *p = new C;
```

it seems confusing because the address of that `C` object is stored in a `B` pointer, but is is legal in C++ because a `C` object is in fact `B` object, because it inherits (has a "is a" relationship) from `B`. When you call `f()`on that `B` pointer storing a `C` object, polymorphism is enabled because the method is `virtual`: it selects the `C`-version of the `f()` method, and that is why you see a `C` printed.

When you remove the `virtual` polymorphism is disabled the the `C` object is seen as a `B` object, and the `B`-version of `f()` is selected. Then you see "`B`" on your screen.

> Why does the following code print more than "CPP!"?

From [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/), it says that:

> The switch statement has a somewhat peculiar syntax inherited from the
>   early times of the first C compilers, because it uses labels instead
>   of blocks. In the most typical use (shown above), this means that
>   break statements are needed after each group of statements for a
>   particular label. If break is not included, all statements following
>   the case (including those under any other labels) are also executed,
>   until the end of the switch block or a jump statement (such as break)
>   is reached.

So, try this instead:

```
int main ()
{
    int x[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    for(int y:x)
    {
        switch(y)
        {
            case 1:cout<<"C";break; // <- notice the 'break'!
            case 3:cout<<"P";break;
            case 7:cout<<"P";break;
            case 8:cout<<"!";break;
        }
    }
}
```