# Validity of forcing at least one iteration of for loop with goto statement

Tags: c, language-lawyer, goto

Disclaimer: I know it is obscure, and I would not program like that. I am aware of the preferred `do-while` statement, rather than that, the question is more about validity of a specific language construct.

---

Is `goto` always supposed to omit *conditional expression* of the `for` loop? From what I observed it skips both the first (i.e. initializing) and second expressions. Will this always happen this way or is this behavior purely compiler dependent?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int m = 5;

    goto BODY;
    for (m = 0; m < 5; m++)
        BODY: puts("Message"); // prints "Message" once

    printf("m = %d\n", m); // prints m = 6

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"it skips both first (i.e. initializing) and second expression"*. Yup. *"the question is more about validity of a language construct"* The language construct is invalid for all sensible programmers, because there are much better ways to do the same thing (and don't require approval by language lawyers).

Comment: @user3386109: Sensible or not, there are also people who write C/C++ compilers and no matter how it looks, the `goto` is still part of the language.

Comment: I don't know it for a fact, but I suspect that `goto` into the body of a loop (if the compiler permits it at all) results in "undefined behavior".

Comment: @user3386109 There is no such thing as "invalid for all sensible programmers". A language construct is either valid or invalid according to the language standard. In this case, the behaviour of the program is well-defined, because the construct is valid.

Comment: @HotLicks: According to the C90 Rationale document [3.6.2](https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/rat/c6.html#3-6-2), It was considered to disallow that practice, but finally they left it as is, so to not break existing code.

Comment: On a somewhat related note, see [Duff's Device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/514118/how-does-duffs-device-work). It doesn't use `goto`, but it's still a bit surprising when you first see it, due to how it uses `switch` to jump into the middle of the `do..while` loop.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, you're jumping over both `m = 0` and `m < 5`, and this is as it should be.

```
for (A; B; C)
    D;
```

is equivalent to

```
{
    A;
  loop:
    if (B)
    {
        D;
        C;
        goto loop;
    }
}
```

There is no way to transfer control to a point between `A` and `B`.

The semantics of your loop are exactly like this "pure goto" version:

```
int m = 5;
goto BODY;
m = 0;
loop:
if (m < 5) 
{
  BODY: puts("Message"); // prints "Message" once
   m++;
   goto loop;
}
printf("m = %d\n", m); // prints m = 6
```

Answer (score 6):

> Does goto is always supposed to omit conditional expression of the for
>   loop?

Yes. A goto jump is always an unconditional jump and the execution will carry from the *label* from there.

From C11 draft, *§ 6.8.6.1 The goto statement*:

> A goto statement causes an unconditional jump to the statement
>   prefixed by the named label in the enclosing function.

With the only exception being:

> The identifier in a goto statement shall name a label located
>   somewhere in the enclosing function. **A goto statement shall not jump
>   from outside the scope of an identifier having a variably modified
>   type to inside the scope of that identifier.**

Comment: Could you explain what that exception means?

Answer (score 4):

The `goto` statement in your code is causing an unconditional jump to a statement inside a `for` loop.When that statement is executed,the flow of the program is supposed to be dependent on the conditional expression in the loop.So,yes initialization inside the loop is skipped.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a `do/while` loop, for example if you have the following for loop:

```
for(A ; B ; C)
{
     D;
}
```

You should use the following do/while loop:

```
A;
do
{
     D;
     C;
}while(B);
```

which will force a first iteration.

**EDIT**

See the comment by chux: If `D;` contains `continue`, this way will not work, you will need another way

**EDIT II**

As the question was edited, this answer is no longer the direct answer to the question, but I won't remove it as it might helps someone...

Comment: This is the right approach as long as `D;` does not contain `continue;`

Comment: OTOH, OP is changing the aim of the post.  May want to review the question.

Answer (score 2):

A goto statement in C programming provides an **unconditional** jump from the 'goto' to a labeled statement in the same function.

Note the **unconditional** term here.

so yes it is supposed to omit conditional expression of `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

This is perfectly legal in c. There's nothing wrong in jumping into a for loop so long as you don't skip over any declarations or initialisations of automatic variables.

In you case, m is incremented once and the loop terminates due to the stopping condition being met.