# if statement doesn't work in the block of switch?

Tags: c++

I wrote a simple function as the following, but it does not work as expected, in C++, the *if* statement doesn't work in the block of *switch*？

```
void any2ten(string origin, int type)
{
    if(! (type == 2 || type == 8 || type == 16))
    {
        cout << "unsupport this " << endl;
        return;
    }

    int result = 0;

   for (int index = 0; index < origin.length(); index++)
    {
        int tmp = 0;
        switch (origin[index])
        {
            if (type == 16) 
            {
            case 'F':
            case 'f':
                tmp = 15 * pow(type, index); break;
            case 'E':
            case 'e':
                tmp = 14 * pow(type, index); break;
            case 'D':
            case 'd':
                tmp = 13 * pow(type, index); break;
            case 'C':
            case 'c':
                tmp = 12 * pow(type, index); break;
            case 'B':
            case 'b':
                tmp = 11 * pow(type, index); break;
            case 'A':
            case 'a':
                tmp = 10 * pow(type, index); break;
            case '9':
                tmp = 9 * pow(type, index); break;
            case '8':
                tmp = 8 * pow(type, index); break;
        }
        if (type == 8 || type == 16) 
        {
            case '7':
                tmp = 7 * pow(type, index); break;
            case '6':
                tmp = 6 * pow(type, index); break;
            case '5':
                tmp = 5 * pow(type, index); break;
            case '4':
                tmp = 4 * pow(type, index); break;
            case '3':
                tmp = 3 * pow(type, index); break;
            case '2':
                tmp = 2 * pow(type, index); break;
        }
    case '1':
        tmp =  1 * pow(type, index); break;
    case '0':
        tmp =  0; break;

    default:
        cout << "wrong character has got" << endl;
        return;
        break;
    }
    result += tmp;
  }
  cout << result << endl;
}
```

while I test the function as *any2ten("aa", 8)*, the result is 90 rather than *wrong character*.

is there anything wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: See also Duff's Device : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/514118/how-does-duffs-device-work

Comment: The indentation of this code is outright hostile to the readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `switch` statement doesn't work the way you imagine that it works. The way it behaves is not as a substitute of an `if`-`else if`-`else`, but somewhat differently.

Upon encountering the `switch` the process will jump to the code following the correct `case`. This means that you actually completely skip the execution of the `if` that you have placed there.

And yes, it does look weird, since you assume that because you have the curly braces you must execute `if` condition or not enter into them at all, but this is simply not the case.

Answer (score 4):

The `if` statement works fine in the block of a `switch`, you've just put it in a place where it never gets executed. The `switch` statement jumps to the corresponding `case`, that is its purpose. Whatever it jumps to, it will skip over the `if`, so the `if` never executes.

If you were to add code to make it possible to jump to between the `switch` and the `if`, then the `if` would execute normally. You could do this with a loop of any kind or a `goto`.

A `default` is only taken if *no* `case` is matched. Otherwise, the `switch` jumps to the matching `case`.

Answer (score 0):

Well the placement of your if-statement doesn't really make sense. The switch-statement jumps to the corresponding case and then exists, hence your if-statement won't be executed. And I wouldn't recommend to use goto, cause it's considered as a bad-practice.