# When can I leave out "break" in switch loop?

Tags: c++

I just solved 1st exercise on [learncpp, chaper 7.8](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/78-function-pointers/). I tested their version of switch loop and it works, but I wonder it's without `break`, shouldn't in this case such code cause undesired behavior? When can I leave out `break`?

Here is my version(which also works correctly):

```
switch (op)
    {
    case '+': {
        return add;
            break;}
    case '-': {
        return subtract;
        break;}
    case '*': {
        return multiply;
        break;}
    case '/': {
        return divide;
        break;}
    default: ;
    }
```

Comment: 1st of all `switch` isn't a loop. And there's no need to have a `break;` statement after the `return`statements.

Comment: It depends if you want fall through or not.  If you don't you need `break`.  If not then you don't.

Comment: Read about what `break` and `return` do and the answer will become clear. Don't rely on testing to learn C++.

Comment: Also, I would recommend learning C++ from a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead of internet tutorials.

Comment: The word "switch" doesn't exist on the page you link to. Thus, there's no way to answer. Further, questions *must* be self contained. All information necessary to know what the question is must be *in the question*. Thus, asking us to go look at code on some other site is off-topic.

Answer (score 9):

Without `break`, the flow of execution will simply continue to the next case - unless you jump in some other way of course (like `return`ing, in your case). This is known as *fall-through*.

Whether this is a bug or not depends on the program. It can be useful if (for example) you want multiple `case`s to have the same action:

```
switch (op)
{
    case '+':
        return add;
        break;  // these breaks do nothing - we have already returned!
    case '-':
        return subtract;
        break;
    case 'x':  // fall through to '*'
    case '*':
        return multiply;
        break;
    case '/':
        return divide;
        break;
}
```

Comment: A great example of Fall-through in action is [Duff's Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514118/how-does-duffs-device-work)

Answer (score 5):

Note that C++ does not *insist* on your using `break`, but often `switch` cases depend on them, to obviate the useful *follow through* feature.

You can remove a `break` with no effect on your program if program control never reaches it: None of the `break` statements after the `return` statements are reachable, so you can safely remove them.

You also don't need an empty `default` label either.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are new to C++, consider that:

- Anytime your code reaches a `return` statement, your current function/method will end and return the specified valued without executing any more line of codes. So your `break` statements are never going to be reached.
- When a `break` is reached, the current `switch`, `while` or `for` will end. And the flow will continue outside of its scope `{...}`.
- If you do not use `break` in a `switch case` then the flow just continues (even to the next case).

Answer (score 3):

It may be useful to you to understand what a `switch` is doing under the covers.

essentially this:

```
enum command {
    add, subtract, multiply, divide, error
};

command foo(char op)
{
    switch (op)
    {
    case '+': {
        return add;
            break;}
    case '-': {
        return subtract;
        break;}
    case '*': {
        return multiply;
        break;}
    case '/': {
        return divide;
        break;}
    default: 
      break;
    }
    return error;
}
```

Is logically the same as this:

```
command foo_that_will_give_people_seizures(char op)
{
    if (op == '+') goto plus_;
    if (op == '-') goto minus_;
    if (op == '*') goto mpy_;
    if (op == '/') goto div_;
    goto break_;

    plus_:
    return add;
    goto break_;   // notice how this statement cannot be reached.

    minus_:
    return subtract;

    mpy_:
    return multiply;

    div_:
    return divide;

    break_:
        ;
    return error;
}
```

and the statement `break;` appearing in any of the cases in the first function is equivalent to `goto break_` in the second.

ps. you won't win any friends writing code like this. People like to pretend that `goto` is a bad thing in c++ ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You should be aware that break should be left out on `default:` (if the default is the last case) where the code flow basically reaches the end and doesn't need to get `break`.

The very purpose of `break` is to prevent code to continue to next case(s) when the actual case is true. `return` however, returns the given statement in the case and breaks the `switch`. If you are considering to return inside `switch` cases, then instead of using `break`, you may use `return foobar;` It will break by returning whatever you wish to return.