# c++ Do-while loop inside switch-case Statement

Tags: c++, switch-statement, do-while

Could someone explain me the program flow for this step by step? I don't understand how the program enters the do-while loop in the first place as n%3=1 and Case 0 should not be entered according to my understanding. 
Thanks in Advance!

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int n = 3;
    int i = 0;

    switch (n % 2) {
    case 0:
        do {
            ++i;
    case 1: ++i;
        } while (--n > 0);
    }

    std::cout << i;
}
```

Comment: This looks like a variant of a so-called `Duff's device` and it should not be ever used.

Comment: Related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514118/how-does-duffs-device-work

Comment: That's some delicious looking spaghetti you found

Comment: Clever code should be well documented.  Even if it is using the famous (infamous?) Duff's device.