# Value passed to function is different than value received

Tags: c

I am creating a program to solve sudoku which contains a struct for each cell that contains the value of the cell and all possible values for the cell as an int with each bit corresponding to a possible value.

To update every cell I have a function called applyMask which removes the bit corresponding to the number of the cell from all other cells that are affected by this cell. This function works properly in testing however when I loop through all cells a large number is passed instead of the correct number. For example, it will pass x  is 0 and y is 2 properly but then instead of passing x is 0 and y is 3 next it will pass x is 4199111 and y is 1. In gdb, the function is passed x is 0 and y is 3 however upon stepping into the function it says that x is 4199111 and y is 1. The function called:

```
typedef struct Cell
{   int values;
    int value;
} cell;

void getSection(int pos, int *section1, int *section2)
{   switch(pos % 3){
    case 0:
        *section1 = pos + 1;
        *section2 = pos + 2;
    case 1:
        *section1 = pos - 1;
        *section2 = pos + 1;
    case 2:
        *section1 = pos - 2;
        *section2 = pos - 1;
    }
}

void applyMask(cell sudokuBoard[9][9], int x, int y)
{   int mask = ~(1<<(sudokuBoard[x][y].value-1));

    for(int maskP = 0; maskP < 9; maskP++)
    {   sudokuBoard[maskP][y].values &= mask;
        sudokuBoard[x][maskP].values &= mask;
    }

    int sectionX1;
    int sectionX2;
    getSection(x, &sectionX1, &sectionX2);
    int sectionY1;
    int sectionY2;
    getSection(y, &sectionY1, &sectionY2);

    sudokuBoard[sectionX1][sectionY1].values &= mask;
    sudokuBoard[sectionX1][sectionY2].values &= mask;
    sudokuBoard[sectionX2][sectionY1].values &= mask;
    sudokuBoard[sectionX2][sectionY2].values &= mask;
}
```

And is called by

```
for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        applyMask(sudokuBoard, i, j);
```

Comment: Ah @Yunnosch, unwind accepted

Comment: Note that `int pos; pos % 3` has 5 possible outcomes: 2,1,0,-1,-2.  Good code would not rely on the calling code to only supply non-negative `pos`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you familiar with the keyword `break` and its use in the `case` parts of a `switch()`?

This:

```
switch(pos % 3){
 case 0:
     *section1 = pos + 1;
     *section2 = pos + 2;
 case 1:
     *section1 = pos - 1;
     *section2 = pos + 1;
 case 2:
     *section1 = pos - 2;
     *section2 = pos - 1;
 }
```

will always execute *all* the `case`:s code, since they don't have `break`s in them. This is known as "fall-through" behavior, and can be very handy when intended.

You should add `break`s, so it looks like this:

```
switch(pos % 3){
case 0:
    *section1 = pos + 1;
    *section2 = pos + 2;
    break;
case 1:
    *section1 = pos - 1;
    *section2 = pos + 1;
    break;
case 2:
    *section1 = pos - 2;
    *section2 = pos - 1;
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate how this explains the high unexpected values. It is true and very convincingly a serious problem, but I don't see how this answers the actual question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514118/how-does-duffs-device-work

Comment: @Yunnosch at a guess, one of the section variables is being returned as -1, and then being used to index into the array, so seemingly random data is being returned.

Comment: that. It will go out of bounds and that's a 32-bit pointer on the stack or sth.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to the end of getSection and you'll see that the missing breaks are causing *section1 and *section2 to go negative:

```
printf("pos: %d, *sec1: %d, *sec2: %d\n", pos, *section1, *section2);
```

Here's the beginning of these outputs:

```
pos: 0, *sec1: -2, *sec2: -1
pos: 0, *sec1: -2, *sec2: -1
pos: 0, *sec1: -2, *sec2: -1
pos: 1, *sec1: -1, *sec2: 0
pos: 0, *sec1: -2, *sec2: -1
pos: 2, *sec1: 0, *sec2: 1
pos: 0, *sec1: -2, *sec2: -1
```

This then makes these lines in applyMask access outside the bounds of sudokuBoard:

```
sudokuBoard[sectionX1][sectionY1].values &= mask;
sudokuBoard[sectionX1][sectionY2].values &= mask;
sudokuBoard[sectionX2][sectionY1].values &= mask;
sudokuBoard[sectionX2][sectionY2].values &= mask;
```